# pyquery not installing on google cloud console

Tags: python, pyquery, google-cloud-console

I am trying to install pyquery on google cloud console.
I tried the command

pip install pyquery

which worked fine on my local system. But when i run it on cloud console it gives the following error.

pyquery installation error

[pyquery installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUXFP.png)

Thanks for any help.